# How to click on material checkbox by clicking on td of table

Tags: angular

I want to make checkbox checked on click on td. i tried with reference variable but i got error.

> DetailComponent.html:97 ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_15(...).click is not a function

```js
<td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"  (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); checkboxElement.click()" >
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    #checkboxElement
    (change)="$event ? singleToggle(element) : null"
    [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)">
    </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template reference variable `#checkboxElement` references the MatCheckbox component instance, not its host element. As a result, there is indeed no `click` method as the error indicated. A method that the [MatCheckbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) component does have is `toggle` and the following should work:

```html
<td (click)="checkbox.toggle()">
  <mat-checkbox #checkbox>
    One
  </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xupmho?embed=1&file=src/app/checkbox-configurable-example.html)